# How to get vim's setting into a bash variable?

Tags: bash, vim

I need to get the current value of some vim settings e.g. `runtimepath`.

I know I can get it in vim using `:set runtimepath`, but I cant find a way to get it into a bash variable.

If you know any way to get it, please help :-(

Comment: why do you want it in a bash variable? are you aware you can put settings in `$HOME/.vimrc`?

Comment: I need to add a directory to the start of `runtimepath`list, then generate a `.vimrc` on the fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I used in my script:

```
TEMP=$( mktemp )
$VIM -c "redir! > $TEMP" -c 'set runtimepath' -c 'q'
```

The output will be redirect to `$TEMP`